# How to change executable file as application program?

Tags: installation

I got the executable file by running the c program and How to change executable file as software

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please be a little bit more specific or detailed about whay you're trying to accomplish, or take a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: tell me how the application softwares are created

Comment: I've posted some links below.. hope they help.. and please edit your Q to add some more detail explaining what you want to do?

Comment: @hash can u join with me in facebook

Comment: thanks.. but I don't use fb.. hope to see you around here in AU..

Comment: @hash ya fine.Give me answer for my other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references:

#### Development Environments:

- [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)
- [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)
- [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Linux Developers (includes Incubating components)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-linux-developers-includes-incubating-components/heliossr1)
- [SO: "C++ IDE for Linux?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)
- [Linux C++ Software Development](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++.html)
- [Comparison of IDEs for C++ and C development on Linux: KDevelop, Eclipse, NetBeans, CodeBlocks and Anjuta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125796/comparison-of-ides-for-c-and-c-development-on-linux-kdevelop-eclipse-netbea)

#### Packaging:

- [Debian Wiki: "Packaging"](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging)
- [The Debian Administrator's Handbook: "Creating a Debian Package"](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/wheezy/debian-packaging.html)
- [How To Create A .DEB Package (Ubuntu / Debian)](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html)
- [Debian Binary Package Building](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/)
- [AU: "How to create a deb package that installs a series of files"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146343/how-to-create-a-deb-package-that-installs-a-series-of-files)
- [AU: "How do I create a .deb file?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215786/how-do-i-create-a-deb-file)
- [SO: "How do I create a native Debian package for static files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176065/how-do-i-create-a-native-debian-package-for-static-files)